# Reset $i++ in a setInterval()

Tags: javascript

I try to reset a counter with jQuery like this

```
 $i = 1;

function theTimer(startTime){

    var counter = $i++;
    var currenTime = parseInt(startTime) + counter;
    var tMin = Math.floor( parseInt(currenTime) / 60 );
    var tHour = Math.floor( parseInt(currenTime) / 3600 );

    (other stuff ...)

}

$('.btn-start-timer').click(function(startTime){
    var startTime = 320;
    banKTimer = setInterval(function() { theTimer(startTime) }, 1000);

});

$('.btn-stop-timer').click(function(){
    stoptheTimer = clearInterval(banKTimer);
});
```

I would like to reset counter=$i++ when I restart the timer.
I forget something but can't find it !

Comment: What issue are you having here?  Doesn't `counter` get reset *every time* you make a new `setInterval` and have it call `theTimer()`?  What are you seeing here and what do you want to be seeing?

Comment: For exemple, i use the timer for 5 second then I  stop the timer. When I restart it, the counter restart from 5 second.and I would like that it restart from 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.btn-stop-timer').click(function(){
    stoptheTimer = clearInterval(banKTimer);
    $i = 0; // Done here to allow you to get $i value for other purpose just 
            // after clearing the interval.
});
```

Comment: I Will test that ! I didn't test that solution

Comment: Great ! Simple ! It works perfectly ! Thanks a lot !